# Should I put my previous class projects on my resume if I am not confident about them but have no other relevant things to show?

Tags: interviewing, resume, internship

I am writing CV to apply for business internship at Google as a undergraduate business student. The problem is the only relevant contents I can put seem to be my class projects, which I don't regard highly because of their rather low quality, in my opinion, and I wouldn't feel confident talking about them in case I get asked in any possible future interview.

Should I put my previous class projects in this case, if the job description indicates they will put me in a specific role according to my interests and skills? I have an appealing (but irrelevant to my major) work experience and a minor that I am more passionate about than the position I am applying for.

Should I even consider putting the seemingly worthless projects on my CV just because they are most relevant contents to the broad rule (i.e., business intern) I am applying for? Can putting a work experience that shows good transferable skills & minor I am passionate about be enough to land me an interview considering it's an internship position?

Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 2):

In my experience writing a resume is all about knowing how to represent yourself.

My favorite example is this:

> **I am a janitor. I clean the floor, and mop the hallways.**

vs

> **I am a custodial technician. I maintain a clean and sanitary environment for the students.**

Who would you hire?

The point of these examples is not to look at your projects (or other relevant experience) as worthless. Rather, even if the project is not amazing, think about what skills you applied in making it:

> "I wrote a survey" becomes **"I designed, distributed, and tallied the results of a questionnaire meant to poll for X in Y target group"**

Sell yourself.

Comment: I'd hire the janitor, the other guy has his head in the clouds :-)